# Software to count clicks and keypresses on macOS

Tags: macos, mouse, keyboard, ergonomics

I'm looking for some software that will count my mouse clicks and keypresses throughout the day, and show a report of my activity.

I would like to use it to inform decisions about ergonomics, such as different types of keyboard and mouse, in order to reduce repetitive strain injury.

It should respect privacy (i.e. not a keylogger, and not uploading to a server).

Statistics such as total and average clicks and keypresses per minute would be great.
Ideally also a breakdown of which keys.

EDIT: I haven't tried it, but maybe something like [Mousotron](http://www.blacksunsoftware.com/mousotron.html) which I think is for Windows only.